# How to configure Flutter Firebase Database onEntryChanged listener correctly?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, state

I'm building a Stateful Flutter page that allows users for follow each other.  Once they both follow the other person I want the state of the page to change and allow the users to message each other.  I created a listener that queried the database once upon loading the page correctly.  Now I'm trying to update the page for user 1 if user 2 makes a change, instantly using onEntryChange and it's not working.  I've gone in and manually deleted entries in my database and the UI state remains the same.  Here is my code...

```
String messageBtn;

     FriendsVideoPageState(){
        fb.child('friends/$id/friends/$uid').onChildChanged.listen(_onEntryChanged);
      }

      _onEntryChanged(Event event) {
        print('Listener..............${event.snapshot.value.toString()}');
        if (event.snapshot.value != null){
          setState(() {
            messageBtn = 'Message';
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            messageBtn = 'Invite';
          });
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

`onChildChanged` is a stream, when I work with streams I often use `StreamBuilder` as it makes things straight forward.

So you could use a `StreamBuilder` with something like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext build) {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: fb.child('friends/$id/friends/$uid').onChildChanged,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return Text(snapshot.data == null ? 'Loading' : snapshot.data.snapshot.value ? 'Message' : 'Invite');
    },
  );
}
```

Every time a new value arrives for the stream the builder method is called and therefore the text content edited.

Comment: I replaced my "Text" widget with the StreamBuilder and it didn't work as intended.  `Snapshot.data` was never not null, it was always an "Instance of Event" even when I added `toString()` to the end.  Any ideas?

Comment: Then there is probably not a problem with how you are handling the data, rather a problem with Firebase database for some reason not to send any data.

My first guesses would be: You don't have permission to read this data. Second: try out the other streams like onValue, onChildAdded, ... if they have any value